# Using Database reference as a global variable or a seperate service like module in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Is it a good practice to initialize the database reference in a global variable.

```
globals.database = client.db(config.dbName);
```

Or should I create separate module for this and export the variable like this -

```
exports.globals = {
    database: null
}
```

and import into controller -

```
const db= require('./globals').database;

exports.postData = function(req, res) {
                    const db = globals.database;
```

I am using Node.js with MongoDB Native Driver. So I will be needing to access database in my controller.

Comment: It's always preferable _not_ to use global objects. If you only need your DB client in the controller, call `client.db(config.dbName)` as a module-local variable (this still assuming you need it in the whole module. The narrower the scope, the better). If you need it elsewhere, then I'd need more details in your question.

Comment: You can think of a standard nodejs API scenario of accessing the database, As I am new to back-end development, I can guess that I will be needing to access the database object in my index.js(server root file), and controller files mostly.

Comment: Don't use your controller for business logic. Business logic should be in the service layer or Database access layer. Also, use a connection pool to maintain the DB connections.

Comment: In that case, you can initialize the DB connection in the `index.js` and then pass it as an argument to the controller methods that need it. I also use @thuva

Answer (score 0):

Given the clarification, you can initialize the DB connection in the `index.js` and then pass it as an argument to the controller methods that need it.

Not sure if it's better, but I also use @Thuvarakan's strategy: in that case, your connection is initialized in the index, passed on to the DB module, and then used to access the DB when asked by the controller.

```
const connection = client.db(config);
const dbAccessLayer = new DbLayer(connection);
const controller = new Controller(dbAccessLayer);
```

The controller would look something like:

```
class Controller {
    constructor(dbAccess) {}

    insertData(data, cb) {
        // Make checks, apply business logic
        this.dbAccess.insertData(data, cb);
    }
    ... 
}
```

And finally the DB access layer would look like:

```
class DbAccess {
    constructor(conn) {}
    insertData(data, cb) {
        conn.insert(...);
    }
    ...
}
```